# In grid view i cannot access the control id's from <EmptyDataTemplate> in its .ascx.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

wcJobShuffling.ascx

//This is an existing code in which a panel navigation contains a grid view.In its ascx.cs the intellisense is not showing the control id's from EmptyDataTemplate.

```
  <asp:Panel ID="navigationJobs" runat="server">
            <table width="98%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" colspan="5" class="tab_not_sltd">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 100%">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="print_row" style="height: 3px">
                                                <a class="blue_nor_lnk" href="#"></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr width="98%" align="center">
                    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="9%" nowrap>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgFirstPage" runat="server" align="absmiddle" border="0" SkinID="imgButtonFirst"
                            OnClick="imgFirstPage_Click" ToolTip="First" CausesValidation="false" />
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPrevPage" runat="server" align="absmiddle" border="0" SkinID="imgButtonPrev"
                            OnClick="imgPrevPage_Click" ToolTip="Previous" CausesValidation="false" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="blue_normal">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSPage" runat="server" CssClass=" blue_normal" align="absmiddle"
                                Width="12px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblto" runat="server" Text="of" CssClass="blue_normal" align="absmiddle"
                                Width="12px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEPage" runat="server" CssClass="blue_normal" align="absmiddle"
                                Width="12px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblof" runat="server" Text="of" CssClass="blue_normal" align="absmiddle"
                                Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalRecords" runat="server" CssClass=" blue_normal" align="absmiddle"></asp:Label>
                        </span>&nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgNextPage" runat="server" align="absmiddle" border="0" SkinID="imgButtonNext"
                            OnClick="imgNextPage_Click" ToolTip="Next" CausesValidation="false" />
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgLastPage" runat="server" align="absmiddle" border="0" SkinID="imgButtonLast"
                            OnClick="imgLastPage_Click" ToolTip="Last" CausesValidation="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="7%" nowrap>
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:Label ID="spangoto" runat="server" Text="Go to Page: " CssClass="black_normal"></asp:Label>
                        <span class="blue_bold">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlgoto" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="black_normal"
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlgoto_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="40px">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="25%" nowrap>
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:Label ID="spanRpg" runat="server" Text="   Records Per Page: " CssClass="black_normal"></asp:Label>
                        <span class="blue_bold">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRows" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="black_normal"
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRows_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="40px">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="10" Selected="True">10</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="20">20</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="50">50</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRecords" runat="server" Text="Records found:" CssClass="black_normal"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalRecordsFound" runat="server" CssClass="black_bold"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="height: 17px; width: 10%" nowrap>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="txtPageNum" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="txtTotalpages" runat="server" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblpg" CssClass="black_normal" runat="server"
                            Text="Page" Visible="false"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="TotalPages" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" CssClass="red_lnk"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td align="right" style="width: 18%">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr height="5px" ><td></td></tr>
                <tr align="left" style="padding-top: 3px" valign="middle">
                    <td colspan="5" style="width: 98%" align="left">
                        <div id="Gridview" width="100%">
                           <asp:HiddenField ID="hidColor" runat="server" />
                           <asp:GridView ID="gvJobShuffling" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="1" CssClass="grid_bg" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="gvJobShuffling_RowDataBound"
                                OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvJobShuffling_SelectedIndexChanging" PagerStyle-Width="0px"
                                PageSize="10" ShowFooter="false" Width="100%" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvJobShuffling_RowCancelingEdit"
                                OnRowEditing="gvJobShuffling_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvJobShuffling_RowUpdating">
                                <RowStyle CssClass="row_even" />
                                <PagerStyle CssClass="hide" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="tble_hdr_not_sltd" />
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="tble_hdr_not_sltd" />
                                <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="row_odd" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <FooterStyle CssClass="hide" />
```

//From Here i am unable to access the control Id's ie...Imtellisense is not showing.

```
                                   <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <table class="confirmation">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                              <asp:Label Text="Records not found"                    ID="lblEmpty" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <RowStyle CssClass="row_even" />
                                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="row_odd" />



                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField >
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            Form ID
                    ``                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblBranchID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BranchID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblProcessID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProcessID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblBranchID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BranchID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblProcessID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProcessID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </EditItemTemplate> 
                                        <ItemStyle Width="0%" />
                                        <HeaderStyle />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="display: none" valign="middle">
                                                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" width="125px">
                                                                    <a>Bill Number</a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style="width: 6px">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td id="Img1dsc" align="right" valign="middle">
                                                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" width="125px">
                                                                    <a>Bill Number</a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style="width: 6px">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <table width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblJobNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>




                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td id="Img3asc" align="right" style="display: none" valign="middle">
                                                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" width="70%">
                                                                    <a>Assign To</a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style="width: 6px">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td id="Img3dsc" align="right" valign="middle">
                                                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" width="70%">
                                                                    <a>Assign To</a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style="width: 6px">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <table width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                  <%# Eval("AssignedToUserName")%>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
```

//Actually in this EditItemTemplate i need to bind the ddlAssignTo.DataSource but this control property is not visible in intellinsense in wcJobsShuffling.ascx.cs

```
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left: 3px">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAssignTo" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAssignTo_SelectionIndexChanged">
                                                      </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="left" valign="middle" visible="false">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSupervisorID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AssignedToUserSupervisorUserID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblJobId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAssignedToUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AssignedToUserName") %>'
                                                        Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right" valign="middle" width="20%">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left: 3px">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right" height="19px" valign="middle">
                                                        <asp:ImageButton SkinID="imgButtonEdit" runat="server" ID="imgEdit" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"
                                                            CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" CausesValidation="false" />&nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton SkinID="imgButtonUpdate" runat="server" ID="imgUpdate" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"
                                                            CommandName="Update" ValidationGroup="GSave" ToolTip="Update" CausesValidation="false" />
                                                        <asp:ImageButton SkinID="imgButtonCancel" runat="server" ID="imgGCancel" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"
                                                            CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />&nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>


                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="9%" style="padding-top: 5px">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgFirstPage1" runat="server" align="absmiddle" border="0" SkinID="imgButtonFirst"
                            OnClick="imgFirstPage_Click" ToolTip="First" CausesValidation="false" />
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPrevPage1" runat="server" align="absmiddle" border="0" SkinID="imgButtonPrev"
                            OnClick="imgPrevPage_Click" ToolTip="Previous" CausesValidation="false" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="blue_normal">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblpg1" runat="server" CssClass="blue_normal" align="absmiddle"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSPage1" runat="server" CssClass=" blue_normal" Width="12px" align="absmiddle"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblto1" runat="server" Text="of" CssClass="blue_normal" Width="12px"
                                align="absmiddle"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEPage1" runat="server" CssClass="blue_normal" Width="12px" align="absmiddle"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblOf1" runat="server" Text="of" CssClass="blue_normal" Visible="false"
                                align="absmiddle"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotPages" runat="server" CssClass=" blue_normal" align="absmiddle"></asp:Label>
                        </span>&nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgNextPage1" runat="server" align="absmiddle" border="0" SkinID="imgButtonNext"
                            OnClick="imgNextPage_Click" ToolTip="Next" CausesValidation="false" />
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgLastPage1" runat="server" align="absmiddle" border="0" SkinID="imgButtonNext"
                            OnClick="imgLastPage_Click" ToolTip="Last" CausesValidation="false" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidSort" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidImageSort1" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidImageSort2" runat="server" />




                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Which event of Gridview you are using to bind **ddlAssignTo** dropdown ???

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAssignTo" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAssignTo_SelectionIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>                         In this             protected void ddlAssignTo_Selection(object sender,EventArgs e){               ddlAssignTo.DataSource                                                            ddlAssignTo.DataBind                                                                                                 }

Comment: //Here the ddlAssignTo_SelectionChandegEvent is also not coming in intellisense.